# How do you serialize a ggplot2 object?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How would you serialize a ggplot2 object to a file and then restore it back from that file?

Comment: `saveRDS` then `readRDS`.

Comment: can you show an example? (feel free to post this as an answer)

Comment: try `?saveRDS` in your R console, and you will have the examples at the bottom of the help page ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you want to plot the age and height of trees in a scatter plot. The data you have is:

```
> tree
   tree.height  age
1          2.2  3.5
2          3.1  4.2
3          0.8 15.8
4          2.5  7.6
5          1.4 12.8
6          1.7 16.4
7          1.2 15.3
8          2.8  6.5
9          0.9 19.5
10         1.6  5.6
```

You can now create and save the plot into an object:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(tree) + geom_point(aes(x=tree.height, y = age))
```

You save it into your current working directory with:

```
saveRDS(p, "myplot.rds")
```

You can read it again into R via:

```
myplot <- readRDS("myplot.rds")
print(myplot)
```

[image: scatterplot]

Comment: I recommend using a file extension: `saveRDS(p, "myplot.rds")`. Also, do not use `$` inside `aes`, you have already specified the data.

Comment: This works, but there should be a big warning that doing so is discouraged. Things are likely to break if a new version of ggplot2 is released. See e.g.: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3625